# SQL query Where clause problem

Tags: sql

I am having trouble finding a query.

I have a table 'NotificationExcludes' that contains 1 column 'Name'.

I have a table 'NotificationEvents' that contains columns: Id, Description.

Now I need to select all the NotificationEvents where the description doesn't start with the values contained in 'NotificationExcludes'.

Small example:

NotificationExcludes contains:

```
Name
The instance was terminated by
```

NotificationEvents:

```
ID  Description
1   There was a failure on ..
2   The instance was terminated by administrator
```

Now I need to select everything except if the description starts with a value that is kept in the 'NotificationExcludes'.

I have tried

```
Select Id, Description 
from NotificationEvent 
WHERE Description NOT IN (select Name form NotificationExcludes)
```

But 2 problems with that:

```
1 The query obviously fails because 'select Name form NotificationExcludes' returns more than 1 record
2 The statement should contain a Like statement where I can use the '%' key. So where description not like 'The instance was terminated by%' can be used somehow
```

Comment: I think you're going to need a cursor for this. Is your code in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Id,Description
FROM NotificationEvents ne
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM NotificationExcludes nx 
                 WHERE ne.Description 
                 LIKE nx.name + '%') /*<--Might need Concat or || here
                                          dependant upon RDBMS*/
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to `JOIN` with a `LIKE` clause on name, appended with `%`.

```
SELECT *
FROM   NotificationEvents ne
       LEFT OUTER JOIN NotificationExcludes nex 
            ON ne.Description LIKE nex.Name + '%' 
WHERE  nex.Name IS NULL
```